# Why does reading with `open(False)` work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this work?

```py
with open(False) as f:
    s = f.read()
```

I know this is an unimportant question but answers I've heard so far about OI open and waiting for an EOF token just doesn't seem to make sense as I've gotten this to work for `True` `1` and `0`

Comment: `False` has an integer value of `0`.  My guess is that `open` is treating it as a [file descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open` can take an integer representing an existing file descriptor, and `False` (aka `0`) is the file descriptor for standard input.